# jquery validation to check status of 3 checkboxes are all checked then enable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, checkbox

I have a form with some text fields, three checkboxes and a submit button.
Currently I have the submit button disabled and it should enable only if ALL three checkboxes are checked.

I have only been able to work out how to enable it with only one checkbox being checked.

How can I make sure all three are checked before enabling the button?

End of form

```
<input name="list1" id="list1" type="checkbox"  value="" >
<input name="list2" id="list2" type="checkbox"  value="" >
<input name="list3" id="list3" type="checkbox"  value="" >
<input id="pay-button" type="image" disabled="disabled" src="paypal.gif" value="" name="save">
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $('#list1').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
   $('#pay-button').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
   $('#pay-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```js
$(function () {
    var $checks = $('#list1, #list2, #list3').change(function () {
        $('#pay-button').prop('disabled', $checks.is(':not(:checked)'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="list1" id="list1" type="checkbox"  value="" >
<input name="list2" id="list2" type="checkbox"  value="" >
<input name="list3" id="list3" type="checkbox"  value="" >
<input id="pay-button" type="image" disabled="disabled" src="//placehold.it/32/fff000" value="" name="save">
```

you can simplify the selector `#list1, #list2, #list3` by adding a common class to those elements and then by using a class selector

Comment: @Jhecht [Introducing Runnable JavaScript, CSS, and HTML Code Snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I added the class selector as mentioned. Thanks for this. works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to compare the count of checked checkboxes and the total amount:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <input name="list1" id="list1" type="checkbox"  value="" >
  <input name="list2" id="list2" type="checkbox"  value="" >
  <input name="list3" id="list3" type="checkbox"  value="" >
</div>
<input id="pay-button" type="image" disabled="disabled" src="paypal.gif" value="" name="save">
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $('#wrapper').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  if ($('#wrapper').find(':checked').size() === $('#wrapper').find(':checkbox').size()) {
   $('#pay-button').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
   $('#pay-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

edit code like below and try again:

HTML :

```
 <input class="chck" name="list1" id="list1" type="checkbox"  value="" >
 <input class="chck" name="list2" id="list2" type="checkbox"  value="" >
 <input class="chck" name="list3" id="list3" type="checkbox"  value="" >
 <input id="pay-button" type="image" disabled="disabled" src="paypal.gif" value="" name="save">
```

JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
      $('.chck').click(function() {
        var isAllChecked = true;

        for(var i = 0; i < $('.chck').length; i++)
        {
            if(!$('.chck')[i].is(':checked'))
                isAllChecked = false;
        }

        if (isAllChecked) {
           $('#pay-button').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
           $('#pay-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
      });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class name to your checkboxes i.e `.checkboxes`

```
 $(".checkboxes").click(function () {

            var blnEnableBtn = false;
            var count = 0;
            $('input:checked').each(function (index, element) {
                count++;
            });

            if (count == 3)
                $("#pay-button").removeAttr('disabled');
            else
                $("#pay-button").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        });
```

Hope it helps .